# Chapman-Robbins-Kiefer Lower Bound for the Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, optimization

Suppose $(X_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ is a sample taken from $U[0,\theta]$ for $\theta > 0$. I want to find the following quantity:

$\displaystyle\sup_{\{\phi:S(\phi)\subset S(\theta),\theta \neq \phi\}}\frac{(\phi-\theta)^{2}}{Var(\frac{f_{\phi}\textbf{(x)}}{f_{\theta}\textbf{(x)}})}$

So that I can get the lower bound for the Chapman-Robbins-Kiefer inequality. However, I've found the following:

$\displaystyle\frac{(\phi-\theta)^{2}}{Var(\frac{f_{\phi}\textbf{(x)}}{f_{\theta}\textbf{(x)}})}=\frac{(\phi-\theta)^{2}}{(\frac{\theta}{\phi})^{n}-1}$

Which seems a difficult function from which to find the supremum for all $0 < \phi < \theta$. Is there another way to approach this problem which can ease up calculations?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much you can do here except take the derivative and set to zero. You can simplify slightly by setting $t:=\frac\phi\theta$ so the function to maximize over $t\in(0,1)$ is
$$
h(t)=\theta^2{(t-1)^2t^n\over1-t^n}
=\theta^2(t-1)^2\left( {1\over1-t^n}-1 \right).
$$
The derivative of $h$ is
$$h'(t)=-\theta^2{(t-1)t^{n-1}(2t^{n+1}-(n+2)t+n)\over(1-t^n)^2},$$
which is zero for $t^*$ between $0$ and $1$ where the polynomial 
$$p(t):=2t^{n+1}-(n+2)t+n$$
equals zero; there's no closed form for $t^*$ except when $n=1$. You can check that $h(t)$ achieves a maximum over $t\in(0,1)$ at $t^*$.