# Cramer-Rao Lower Bound for a Simple Case

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

I am trying to use Cramer Rao Theorem to estimate $\theta$ when $\{X_i\}_1^n$'s are random samples with probability density function
\begin{equation*}
        f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
                        3x^2/\theta^3 \text{, $x \in [0,\theta]$} \\
                        0 \text{ , otherwise}
                    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I realized that I have some fatal misundertanding of Cramer Rao Theorem when I tried to find the $CRLB$. This is what I've done:

Likelihood Function: $L(\{x_i\}_1^n,\theta)=\prod_i f_{X_i}(x_i)= \frac{3^n}{\theta^{3n}}\prod_i x_i^2$

Log-Likelihood Function: $l(\{x_i\}_1^n,\theta)=\sum_i \log(f_{X_i}(x_i))= n\cdot \log(3)-3n\cdot\log(\theta)+\sum_i2\cdot \log(x_i)$

Then $\partial_\theta l =\frac{-3n}{\theta}$, and $\partial_\theta^2 l = \frac{3n}{\theta^2} $.

Then, according to the statement of the theorem I will have:

$$Var(\hat{\theta})\geq \frac{1}{n\mathbb{E}[(\partial_\theta l)^2]}=\frac{-1}{n\mathbb{E}[\partial_\theta^2 l]}$$

But, the two terms at the right side are not equal:

$$\frac{1}{n\cdot (\frac{-3n}{\theta})^2}\neq \frac{-1}{n\cdot \frac{3n}{\theta^2}}$$

(One of them is negative!)

Where am I wrong, I would be glad for any help.

Comment: I think it is better for you to write the complete exercise....your model is not regular thus the condition to apply Cramér Rao are not attained

Comment: The exercise is not much different. We have $n$ samples as I've described above. Firstly it defines $$X_{(n)}:=\text{max}_i{X_i}$$ And says that find an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ based on $X_{(n)}$. (That is $$X_{(n)}\cdot \frac{3n+1}{3n}$$ as I've calculated). And then it says use Cramer-Rao Theorem to show that that is a minimum variance unbiased estimator.

Comment: Cramér Rao inequality cannot be used if the model does not attain certain conditions and your model does not. There is an useful generalization of CRLB by Chapman - Robbins - Kiefer for non regular models. Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705420/chapman-robbins-kiefer-lower-bound-for-the-uniform-distribution… is an example applied to the uniform distribution

Comment: There are different and suitable ways to prove that your unbiased estimator is UMV

Comment: The support of your density depends upon $\theta$ and you should consider this when deriving the log-likelihood. (Maybe by using Leibnitz rule). For this reason the expected value of your score is not $0$, but negative, and the maximum likelihood is reached at $\widehat{\theta} \rightarrow 0$.